# variant doesn't contan an object, lotus script

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

I am writing this lotus scritp and I cannot figure the error out
the error is variant doen't contain an object...
It will be appreciated if anyone can help
Thanks in advance

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
Dim session As New NotesSession 

Dim ws As NotesUIWorkspace
Dim adminp As NotesAdministrationProcess
Dim userName As Variant

userName = workspace.Prompt(PROMPT_OKCANCELEDIT, _
"User", _
"Enter the user to delete")

noteID$ = adminp.DeleteUser( userName , False , DelMailFile , "Terminations" , False )


End Sub
```

Comment: still the same error

Comment: "option declare" is your friend....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing your UI workspace variable `ws` so initialize it with New:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
```

Also, you are then calling Prompt on a variable called `workspace` which should be changed to `ws` as that is the name of your declared variable:

```
userName = ws.Prompt(...
```

Also, you are not initializing the adminp variable so do something like this before calling adminp.DeleteUser():

```
Set adminp = session.CreateAdministrationProcess("Server/Org")
```

Finally you are referring to a variable called DelMailFile which is not declared. So make sure to declare it or use the proper integer value as defined in the [help for DeleteUser](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ca/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DELETEUSER_METHOD_ADMINP.html).

Comment: Thanks per henrik but it still generates the same error